# Operaciones matematicas tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla `HTML` en la que quiero realizar operaciones matematicas, pero no se llega a ejecutar el código.

```
function formula() {
var cantidad = document.mytable.cantidad.value;
var precio_unitario = document.mytable.precio_unitario.value;
var iva = document.mytable.iva.value;
 try{
  cantidad = (isNaN(parseInt(cantidad)))? 0 : parseInt(cantidad);
  iva = (isNaN(parseInt(iva)))? 0 : parseInt(iva);
  precio_unitario = (isNaN(parseInt(precio_unitario)))? 0 : parseInt(precio_unitario);
  total = (isNaN(parseInt(total)))? 0 : parseInt(total);

  document.mytable.total.value = (cantidad*iva*precio_unitario);
}
catch(e) {}
}


<table name="mytable" id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
            <th width="18%">Descripción del artículo</th>
            <th width="5%">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th width="5%">%DTO</th>
            <th width="5%">IVA</th>
            <th width="7%">Precio Total</th>
            <th width="12%">Inspección de recepción</th>
            <th width="12%">Comentarios</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="artiuclo" name="articulo" class="form-control">
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" id="precio_unitario" name="precio_unitario" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="descuento_porcentaje" name="descuento_porcentaje" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="iva" name="iva" class="form-control">
       </td>
       <td><input type="text" id="precio_total" name="precio_total" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()">
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" id="inspeccion" name="inspeccion" class="form-control"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="comentarios" name="comentarios" class="form-control"></td>
     </tr>
      <th>Total</th>
<td><input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="form-control"></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cqLg2mh7/13/

Comment: Estas usando algún tipo de Framework de Javascript? No se puede acceder a elementos con document.mytable etc... en Javascript nativo.

Comment: No, solo tengo funciones ajax.

Comment: Te dejo una respuesta entonces sobre como tendrías que hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He adaptado el código:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th width="5%">Cantidad</th>
            <th width="18%">Descripción del artículo</th>
            <th width="5%">Precio Unitario</th>
            <th width="5%">%DTO</th>
            <th width="5%">IVA</th>
            <th width="7%">Precio Total</th>
            <th width="12%">Inspección de recepción</th>
            <th width="12%">Comentarios</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="artiuclo" name="articulo" class="form-control">
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" id="precio_unitario" name="precio_unitario" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()"></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="descuento_porcentaje" name="descuento_porcentaje" class="form-control"></td>
          <td><input type="number" id="iva" name="iva" class="form-control">
       </td>
       <td><input type="number" id="precio_total" name="precio_total" class="form-control" onKeyUp="formula()">
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" id="inspeccion" name="inspeccion" class="form-control"></td>
     <td><input type="text" id="comentarios" name="comentarios" class="form-control"></td>
     </tr>
      <th>Total</th>
<td><input type="number" id="total" name="total" class="form-control"></td>
</tbody>
</table> 

<script>
function formula() {
 var cantidad = document.getElementById('cantidad').value;
 var precio_unitario = document.getElementById('precio_unitario').value;
 var iva = document.getElementById('iva').value;    

      document.getElementById('total').value = (cantidad*iva*precio_unitario);
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Prueba y comenta

> **EDITADO**: Código editado, cambiado algunos ***inputs*** tipo ***text*** por ***number***

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqLg2mh7/32/ Aquí mismo lo tienes pero no rellena el campo total

Comment: Esa solución si funciona perfectamente. Pruebala en local, en lugar de JSFiddle. Si bien, yo cambiaría el tipo de *input* por `"number"` para no tener que estar comprobando si es texto o número.

Comment: Tienes razón @DaniAguado, Ahora lo edito para que quede mejor. Gracias

Comment: Además, creo que lo que él quiere es que se rellene el campo total del final de la fila (`precio_total`), no el de abajo... debería confirmarnoslo. De ese modo, luego deberían sumarse todos los inputs de esa columna para sacar el total... pero eso ya es otra historia.

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript nativo no puedes acceder a los elementos del DOM como lo estas intentando, con `document.mytable.cantidad.value`

Tienes que acceder de la siguiente forma:

`document.getElementById('cantidad').value`

Tienes otros métodos para acceder aquí:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_elements.asp

Además, tienes una variable no definida en la función formula(), `precio`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqLg2mh7/27/ Acabo de utilizar  `document.getElementById` y no funciona tampoco